# Wait for clean shutdown before scaling down a pod on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

I need to scale down the number of pods in a replica controllers. However, I need a clean scale down:

- Stop to send load on the pods that will be scaled down
- Wait for the pod to have finished to handle the load
- Delete the pod

I do not want a pod to be deleted when it is still doing stuff. Is there a way to do that with Kubernetes?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Termination of Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination) section in the pods user guide. You might wish to implement a [preStop hook](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/container-environment/#hook-details) to ensure traffic is drained before the TERM signal is sent to the processes in the pod.

Comment: Will the loadbalancer stop to send load just before executing the preStop hook?

Comment: The first link has been moved to https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination